# Can I use dismiss for screen movement using NavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using NavigationController to operate the view.

If the value is exceeded on the first view and the value is not satisfied with the 'if' on the second view, I hope 'dismiss' will work.

I have made a similar simple example.

```
//First View
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func goSecond(_ sender: Any) {
        let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
}
```

```
//Second View
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func goThird(_ sender: Any) {
        let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController
            
        let num = 1
        DvC.num = num
            
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
}
```

```
//Third View
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var num = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("num: ")
        print(num)

        if(num != 2) {
            print("Success")
//            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
//            navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Failed")
        }
    }
}
```

The third view shows "Success", but the codes below it do not work.

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // not work
navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // not work
```

Pressing the button on the first view moves to the second view, and pressing the button on the second view moves to the third view.

If the value passed when I go to the third view is not satisfied with 'if', I want to go back to the first view.

I want the second and third views to end, not just the screen shift.

Like the `finish()` of Android.

How can I exit the second and third views and return to the first view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing the view controllers onto the stack. `dismiss` is for dismissing VCs presented **modally**.

What you want to do is pop the VC to go back one.

```
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

or to go back to the root view.

```
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```